# How to prevent my website from being scrolled horizontally?

Tags: html, css, iphone, scroll

I am trying to make my website compatible with different devices. On a computer, only the content is shown and the user can't scroll horizontally. On portrait mode of an iPhone, there is a horizontal scrollbar. I tried using overflow-x to prevent this, but it doesn't fix the problem. Here is the temporary link to the [website](http://msolonko.net16.net). The issue does't occur in landscape mode. This is what it looks like on iPhone: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like the offender is here in the markup:

```
<p id="footerP">Mykyta Solonko 2016</p>
```

The styles have this rule:

```
#footerP {
  left: 1090px
}
```

That is causing that paragraph to render on the far right of the screen. It's tough to see b/c it's white on that light background color.

[image: screenshot]

Remove that rule and the space on the right goes away.

Comment: Wow, nice catch. It would take me years to notice that probably.

Answer (score 1):

Along with what Jonathan has added, you also set the width two divs which causes horizontal scrolling.

```
<div id="main">
<div id="header">
<div id="pln">
```

These are set to 700px, 650px and 500px respectively, which means that if you are using an iPhone 5 which has a width of 320px, the user will have to sroll horizontally to view that rest of the content since you are telling the browser to set the elements mentioned to that width.

Set these to a percentage value or a value that you know is smaller than the 'standard' small screens.

You also need to restructure the layout of your page as the size of the viewport changes. That is the biggest problem with your page, not the specific CSS rules but the structure of your content.

Try sketching the structure of your pages based on Desktops, Tablets and Smart Phones as your target and then design each page from there.